# What are the major uses of the rank of a set?

Tags: set-theory

We can define the rank of set $X$ as the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that $X \in V_\alpha$, where $V_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$-th stage of the [cumulative hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe). However, I have yet to see this idea applied anywhere, and I spend a LOT of time on wikipedia. What are its major uses?

Comment: The existence of a rank function is equivalent to the axiom of regularity. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213639/where-is-axiom-of-regularity-actually-used/ may interest you.

Comment: The rank is something to do induction on. That is the main (and frequent) use.

Comment: Besides being a ladder for induction, it’s useful for [Scott’s trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick).

Comment: Obviously related to doing induction, it's useful for definitions by recursion. You can define a property (blank) of sets by saying that a set has property (blank) if all of its elements have property (blank). This looks circular, but it's a definition by recursion on rank.